# I'm having trouble determining where the Close Holes filter from Meshlab is found

Tags: algorithm, mesh, meshlab

So I know Meshlab is built on top of an opensource VCG Library found [here](http://vcg.isti.cnr.it/~cignoni/newvcglib/html/index.html) so I figured I'd be able to find which part of the code is involved in the Close Holes filter but I'm having some trouble.

If possible could anyone point me to what algorithm is being used or where to search in the VCG source (or Meshlab source) to find the code for the filter?

I wanted to incorporate it in something I'm doing without having to call meshlabserver + filter script.

Answer (score 2):

Open meshlab's "close holes" filter.  Click Help.  Notice an unusual phrase "closing a hole."  Download the source code distribution, currently MeshLabSrc_AllInc_v133.tgz.

```
cd meshlab/src
find . -type f -print0 |xargs -0 grep "closing a hole"
```

Notice the one hit: `./meshlabplugins/filter_meshing/meshfilter.cpp:` ... `"After closing a hole the faces that have been created are left selected.` ...

Edit meshfilter.cpp, and find just above that line, `case FP_CLOSE_HOLES:`.

Grep again for `FP_CLOSE_HOLES`.  Find the call to `EarCuttingFill`.

Grep `EarCuttingFill`.  Find no definitions for it.  Google instead, and find its [VCG reference](http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/diamondback/api/vcglib/html/classvcg_1_1tri_1_1Hole.html).

A few more clicks yields the [source code](http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/diamondback/api/vcglib/html/hole_8h_source.html#l00584).

**Edit:** those URLs from 2014 are dead.  In 2018, try http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/vcglib/html/classvcg_1_1tri_1_1Hole.html and http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/vcglib/html/hole_8h_source.html#l00584